Stored procedure in snowflake to convert all views to table
I have created a stored procedure that can convert all views from a schema into tables in another schema but it simply does not run in Snowflake.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_VIEWS_TO_TABLES()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    SOURCE_SCHEMA STRING;       
    TARGET_SCHEMA STRING;       
    CURRENT_VIEW STRING;        
    CREATE_TABLE_SQL STRING;    

BEGIN
    -- Assign values to the source and target schemas
    SOURCE_SCHEMA := 'SOURCE.STAGE';
    TARGET_SCHEMA := 'TARGET.STAGE.TABLES';

    -- Iterate through all views in the source schema
    FOR VIEW_NAME IN (
        SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SOURCE_SCHEMA
    )
    DO
        -- Assign the current view name
        CURRENT_VIEW := VIEW_NAME;

        -- Construct the SQL statement to create a table from the view
        CREATE_TABLE_SQL := 
            'CREATE TABLE "' || TARGET_SCHEMA || '"."' || CURRENT_VIEW || '" AS 
             SELECT * FROM "' || SOURCE_SCHEMA || '"."' || CURRENT_VIEW || '"';

        -- Execute the dynamic SQL statement
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE_TABLE_SQL;
    END FOR;

    RETURN 'All views have been copied successfully!';
END;
$$;

Please advise.

What is the error message that you are getting ? Any ideea why you are having the target schema as  'TARGET.STAGE.TABLES' ?

I have created a stored procedure that can convert all views from a schema into tables in another schema but it simply does not run in Snowflake. If it does not run, then it implies it either does not do what you want, or it is not created, thus your statement feels a touch impossible. Also please describe how you experience it "not working" because it is too exhausting to guess based on zero details.

running you procedure I get the error: Error:'EXPRESSION_ERROR' on line 14 at position 21 : SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 29 (line 45) invalid identifier 'SOURCE_SCHEMA' (line 45)

If I change your SQL to:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_VIEWS_TO_TABLES()
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
    SOURCE_SCHEMA STRING;       
    TARGET_SCHEMA STRING;       
    CURRENT_VIEW STRING;        
    CREATE_TABLE_SQL STRING;    
    c1 CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SO';
BEGIN
    -- Assign values to the source and target schemas
    
    SOURCE_SCHEMA := 'SO.SO';
    TARGET_SCHEMA := 'SO._TO';

    OPEN c1;
    -- Iterate through all views in the source schema
    FOR VIEW_NAME IN c1
    DO
        -- Assign the current view name
        CURRENT_VIEW := VIEW_NAME.TABLE_NAME;

        -- Construct the SQL statement to create a table from the view
        CREATE_TABLE_SQL := 
            'CREATE TABLE ' || TARGET_SCHEMA || '."' || CURRENT_VIEW || '" AS 
             SELECT * FROM ' || SOURCE_SCHEMA || '."' || CURRENT_VIEW || '"';

        -- Execute the dynamic SQL statement
        -- for debuging this SQL
        --RETURN :CREATE_TABLE_SQL;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE_TABLE_SQL;
    END FOR;

    RETURN 'All views have been copied successfully!';
END;
$$;

it will copy from db.schema so.so to database.schema so._to
To get it working I run your given SQL, and got the error:

Error:'EXPRESSION_ERROR' on line 14 at position 21 : SQL compilation error:
error line 4 at position 29 (line 45) invalid identifier 'SOURCE_SCHEMA' (line 45)

so I changed the SQL to:
    FOR VIEW_NAME IN (
        SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = :SOURCE_SCHEMA
    )

which gave:

092234 (P0000): Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 16 at position 4 : Expression in variant for loop does not evaluate to an array or an object

then I read the FOR doc's and noticed the examples are using a cursor.
so swapped to that, then needed to change CURRENT_VIEW := VIEW_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
Then I changed how you were quoting the database name & schema name, as these should not need to be quoted as "nobody would use special tokens in these, right?"
And I was returning the SQL, so I could run it outside the SP to test it.

OMG thank you so much it worked. The syntax is convoluted but hopefully I will get better at it over time. Thanks again !
